# Estimate multivariate distribution with several variables on real data (continuous and categoricals) and sample from it

Tags: r, nonparametric, survey, copula, multivariate-distribution

I have a complex dataset, collected through a survey, with both continuous (such as Age, Body mass index, etc..) and categorical variables (i.e. Gender, Education, etc..). I want to estimate their multivariate distributions and then sample from it.

I was looking at nonparametric techniques and copula functions suitable on R, but I am struggling and cannot find a solution yet.
Any suggestions on how to proceed on R?

Comment: Since you have multivariate data, it is a good idea to use `rvinereg` package. To the best of my knowledge, it provides an estimation for the vine copula model with continuous and categorical variables.

Comment: Thank! Good suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a small sample that is reliably from the true distribution? Well, to be more exact, from the distribution as sampled? Then simply take a random subset of your dataset.

If that is not good enough, why not? If it is a question of anonymization, you can perturb the values drawn at random. For how much you have to change it, search for "differential privacy".

Or is it because you want to make a new dataset that is much bigger than the real sample? Then again some random fuzzing is a simple approach.

Yes, you could first try to find out the distribution. Any method to do so depends on prior knowledge and has a bias. Modelling a complex dataset is hard - do you really need to do it for your current purpose?

Comment: @chrismorris I want to create a dataset that is much bigger than the real survey sample, as I was recreating the target population. So that I want first to estimate the joint density of my variables, as this was my superpopulation model, and then draw a sample from it, to obtain the finite population.

I see on R that some functions that allow to estimate the multivariate density nonparametrically, such as `PDFEstimator::estimatePDF` or the package `kdevine`, but I am not sure these are the correct solutions

Comment: All estimators of density are biased, i.e. rely on prior knowledge, e,g, about the smoothness of the distribution.

You are trying to solve the hard problem of modelling a multivariate distribution. If there was an R function for this, then the world would not need so many data scientists!